# Corrupted USB Pendrive is not listing in Disk Utility, but listed in ioreg -p IOUSB

Tags: macos, disk-utility, usb, bootable-disk

I was attempting to create a bootable Windows 10 USB stick with help of [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).

I ran it on a Windows 10 VM (via VMWare Fusion) and left Rufus do the job. After a couple of hours, I came back to check the process and found that Rufus failed on about 35-40% and threw out an error. Since then, my USB pendrive stopped listing in VM and in macOS itself.

`diskutil` was also not able to list my USB drive but running `ioreg -p IOUSB` did in fact list my pendrive:
[image: ioreg output]

I think the drive's file system is totally corrupted. Is there anything I can do to restore it since diskutil is not listing it and as a result I can't format it?

Comment: What is the result of the terminal command `diskutil list`?

Comment: @Jean_JD It just lists disk0 and disk1 with their partitions, usb should be disk2 but diskutil doesn't list it

Comment: You can try unplug/plug this usb key, but there is little hope.

Comment: I'm just wondering, if you already had a Windows VM running, why you didn't just let Windows create the installer… it's pretty good at that ;))